# Play and pause audio on same button Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, audio

I try to play and pause an audio file on the same button in my recyclerView adapter. But if I press my "playbtn" it just play and not pause.

Here is my function:

```
fun playmusic(position: Int) {

    val post = posts[position]
    mp  = MediaPlayer()
    mp.setDataSource(post.audioUrl)
    mp.prepareAsync()
    mp.setOnPreparedListener { player ->
        if (player.isPlaying)
            player.pause()
        else{
            player.start()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my clickListner:

```
    playbtn.setOnClickListener {
            playmusic(postPosistion)
            Toast.makeText(context, "You play ${postPosistion + 1}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

Comment: what's the value of your player when your audio is playing ?

Comment: Im not sure but maybe the case is that you're creating new `MediaPlayer` instance each time `playmusic()` is called.

Comment: I think it may be caused by fact you create MP everytime, so everytime `isPlaying` returns false

Comment: The value of player is my Mediaplayer  "mp" / "post.audioUrl".

Comment: Where should create my Mediaplayer? If create it somewhere else in my Adapter it crash when I try to Pause. Cause you mean this row "mp  = MediaPlayer()"? @Gralls

Answer (score 0):

Every `View` object has a method called `setTag`/`getTag`, this is used to store small info about the state of the view.

In your 'play' button's click listener, you can set `tag` with your custom state, it could be anything, an integer, a string, or even a sealed class states. After then, it's just simple if-else logic, in your if condition, check if the `getTag as T(the type of object you previously-stored)`, matches playing state, then pause else play.

Comment: Good suggestion, if I do that it says that it plays the music all-time when I press the button, But there is no sign of "pause". Any clue of what I should do?

Comment: This my adapter https://github.com/Alexanderjansson91/PYT/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/pytapplication/Postadapter.kt.

Comment: I could not understand what you meant by "no sign of pause". When your play button is clicked, you just need to change it's drawable icon to a pause icon with the help of the solution I provided in my answer.